# I get 2 fingers zoom on android but not on ios

Tags: ios, scroll, meta-tags

I was struggling with having 2 finger events on touch devices.Finally I removed all the meta tags from my Html and it made the Android device to work , however I still have problem with iPad.

I read all the other threads about zoom in and tried different variation of this meta tag :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="
    user-scalable=yes,
    width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0"/>
```

but none of them helped have scroll on iPad.

when I have this :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes"  />
```

I get zoom on Android but still no 2 finger pinch or scroll on iPad.

I appreciate any help or suggestion on that.